# Import whole workbook onto a sharepoint list

Tags: excel, powerapp

Is it possible to import a whole workbook onto a sharepoint list? Or have them tabbed somehow so as to use them later on on power apps?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "import spreadsheet"-app?

[image]

Comment: I tried, it fails complaining about active x not supported. Tried it on IE and it fails giving no explanation.

Comment: Make sure you don't have ActiveX disabled in your interne-settings, also I seem to remember that it's not wise to try this using a 64bit browser..

Comment: Also: *There is no other way*, sorry. If this fails (it might still fail, if the spreadsheet is too "complex") you need to search for a 3rd-party tool or write some script manually

Comment: Hi Nils thank you, I tried 32 bit Internet explorer and it failed :(

Comment: It you have multiple spreadsheets in the workbook, try to copy / paste a sheet into a new workbook by itself, then try to upload that.